# Return Multiple Dates Horizontally in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

purchline has

```
itemid, deliverydate, qtyordered

select * from purchline
itemid   deliverydate    qtyordered
74700    01/01/2000      50
74700    01/01/2007      51
74700    01/01/2010      5
```

Q.

I would prefer to see this as a stored procedure and look as follows:

```
itemid  deliverydates                     TotalOrdered 
74700   01/01/2000 01/01/2007 01/01/2010  106
```

Comment: are you querying one itemid at a time?

Comment: I am using MSSMS 2008. Database is MSSQL 2005.

Comment: The purchline TABLE has multiple itemid and it changes every few hours

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edited for SQL Server 2005**

If you are using SQL Server:

```
SELECT itemid
    ,deliverydates = STUFF((SELECT ' ' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR, deliverydate, 101)
                           FROM purchline b 
                           WHERE b.itemid = a.itemid
                           FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '')
    ,TotalOrdered = SUM(qtyordered) 
FROM purchline a
GROUP BY itemid
```

---

Test with the following:

```
-- Setup test data
DECLARE @T1 AS TABLE (
    itemid NVARCHAR(50)
    ,deliverydate DATETIME
    ,qtyordered INT);

INSERT @T1 VALUES ('74700', '20000101', 50)
INSERT @T1 VALUES ('74700', '20070101', 51)
INSERT @T1 VALUES ('74700', '20100101', 5)

-- Return the desired results
SELECT itemid
    ,deliverydates = STUFF((SELECT ' ' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR, deliverydate, 101)
                           FROM @T1 b 
                           WHERE b.itemid = a.itemid
                           FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '')
    ,TotalOrdered = SUM(qtyordered) 
FROM @T1 a
GROUP BY itemid
```

Comment: I have just updated the answer for SQL Server 2005.  Try again.  :)

Comment: ok now how can i store this as a SP so I can do something like; select itemid, customername, deliverydates, etc and call the new Stored Procedure? Or should i post this as a seperate question?

Comment: how can i add a where clause? I am getting way too many deliverydates. purchstatus = 1 (mean this is still open and has not been received) I added WHERE p.itemid = a.itemid and purchstatus = 1 but I am getting a heap of NULL deliverydates

Answer (score 1):

If you are using MySQL:

```
SELECT   ItemID, 
         GROUP_CONCAT(deliverydate SEPARATOR ' ') as deliverydate,
         SUM(qtyordered) qtyordered
FROM     purchline
GROUP BY ItemID
```

Comment: How can this possibly be the correct answer if you are using MSSQL 2005?  `GROUP_CONCAT` is not a valid SQL Server function.

Comment: the answer is i don't know. i posted the answer before the OP says that he was using MySQL. maybe the OP accepts your answer, not mine.

Comment: Your answer makes perfect sense since the OP did not initially specify the RDBMS (and well done for posting the correct answer for MySQL).  The OP did subsequently mention in the comments that the database is "MSSQL 2005" so my question is really for the OP as to how this query worked with MSSQL 2005.  :)

Comment: the title was "Return Multiple Dates Horizontally in SQL"   Totetski answer worked perfectly for me however the date format is not nice. eg. Jul 14 2004 12:00AM Oct 20 2004 12:00AM Jun  6 2005 12:00AM Mar  1 2007 12:00AM

Comment: are you sure my query runs on your server? It's for MySQL only. :)